# Connect SQL Server to SAP Backend (also a SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server-2012, sap-basis

I am trying to connect my SQL Server directly to the SAP backend database so that I don't have to extract the data everyday (for fresh data) using SSIS packages.

Instead I want to create views that will access this data directly (direct querying) and get refreshed periodically.

Can someone give me a link or show/tell me the steps on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the hostname of the backend server, you can do something like this:
`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM hostname.databasename.dbo.tablename`

Comment: How do i connect the remote SQL Server Database to the backend SAP database.

Comment: @querty, use **sp_addlinkedserver** and **sp_dropserver** (once you are done using the linked server) to create a connection to the remote database.  Follow the instructions in the following article from the section titled, _Using Transact-SQL_, (near the bottom of the article):
   [Create Linked Servers (SQL Server Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your data from external SQL server directly in SAP you can define connection to external database in transaction DBCO:
[image: DBCO | New Entry]

Then in your ABAP code you can write SQL statements using OPEN SQL:

```
EXEC SQL. 
  CONNECT TO my_new_connection. 
ENDEXEC. 
...
EXEC SQL. 
  SELECT * INTO TABLE :lt_internal_table FROM dbtable. 
ENDEXEC. 
...
EXEC SQL.
  DISCONNECT my_new_connection.
ENDEXEC.
```

or using Classes `CL_SQL_CONNECTION, CL_SQL_STATEMENT`. An Example program `ADBC_DEMO` show how to use it.